# Adding weight ot variables in a line graph Tableau

Tags: statistics, tableau-api

I have a dataset consisting of calls going to agents (atually 10 of them) per day. These agents can either answer calls or transfer them to a call center. What we are interested in is whether each of these agents answers more calls than he transfers. In order to answer this, I have created a variable for each of these agents:

```
Answered/Transferred
```

I am using line graph to depict these variables per agent over time.
Now if this variable is less than 1 then this agent transferred more calls than he received. The problem now is that this is not a safe way to measure the overall impact of transferred calls. This is because the traffic pertaining to agents 1,2,3 is far greater than the one pertaining to agents 5,6,7 and so on. Therefore, I am trying to come up with a way to "weight" the variables I have created before. That is, somehow include the total number of calls reaching each agent (irrespectively of whether they are getting transferred or answered) in my calculations. That means that if an agent is getting 5 calls per day while another guy is getting 5.000 per day then I should find a way to depict this in my graphs.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Use the sum(calls) and put in on the color shelf (or size).  You can also take the log(sum(calls))  if you want to condense the color range a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to drag weight measure to colors and choose something like temperature diverging. Depending on your viz you can also drag weight measure to size, and for example, make bars or lines thicker to show there are more records there.